# extracting integer data from a string in list

Tags: python, scrape

i am using xpath to scrape some data of a webpage .. the result is as follows

```
['\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tRs\xa021790    \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', '\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tRs\xa023851\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', '\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tRs\xa023905\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', '\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tRs\xa026570\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t']
```

now I need to extract only the integers from the entries in list(if present else 0) ..

the intended output:

```
[0, 21790, 0, 23851, 0, 23905, 0, 26570]
```

I am avoiding 'regex' or any extra modules.

Comment: If you're avoiding regex why did you tag this as regex?

Comment: Your output doesn't match what you describe your input should produce, and there are no leading zeros in your input either. I'd expect that to produce `[0, 21790, 0, 23851, 0, 23905, 0, 26570]` instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes you are right !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to strip away the spaces, and then you can split on the `\xa0` non-breaking space:

```
[0 if not v.strip() else int(v.strip().split()[-1]) for v in inputlist]
```

Demo:

```
>>> inputlist = ['\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tRs\xa021790    \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', '\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tRs\xa023851\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', '\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tRs\xa023905\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', '\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tRs\xa026570\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t']
>>> [0 if not v.strip() else int(v.strip().split()[-1]) for v in inputlist]
[0, 21790, 0, 23851, 0, 23905, 0, 26570]
```

This uses a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#list-displays) to loop over the values, with [`str.strip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to remove the whitespace (all the tabs and carriage returns) and [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split the remaining string on whitespace (where `\xa0` is whitespace too).

Comment: it works right ..can you explain the code and refer to me any tut/book for basic list operation like this .. in a single line (newbie at python )

Comment: @Code_reaper: I linked to the documentation for the specific techniques used here; there is no one tutorial that'd teach these techniques in a compact manner, I don't think. You can try out the different methods in a Python prompt; try them out on individual elements and see what is returned, for example, to give you an idea of what each step does.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it with a single `map` and `filter`:

```
>>> l = ['\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tRs\xa021790    \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', '\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tRs\xa023851\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', '\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tRs\xa023905\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', '\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tRs\xa026570\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t']
>>> map(int, (filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), s) or '0' for s in l))
[0, 21790, 0, 23851, 0, 23905, 0, 26570]
```